# as there is in Roman Catholicism

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Since there is no centralized authority in pentecostalism, **as** there is in Roman Catholicism, it is possible that some faction within the movement could decide to mobilize God’s army in a righteous crusade, but I don’t see this as the inherent logic of the movement.

[Source](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2006/04/12/the-new-face-of-global-christianity-the-emergence-of-progressive-pentecostalism/)

---

I'm not sure what exactly "**as**" means.
Does "**as**" mean "*in the opposite way that there is no centralized authority in pentecostalism*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "in the way that".

It has no necessary connotation of "opposite". A sentence like this would be fine:

> There is a central authority in (X sect), as there is in Roman Catholicism.

In that affirming context, "just as" would be more common, I think; but bare "as" would also be acceptable.

But in your example, after "no", it is expressing the opposite.

Comment: "No" negates "there is (no) centralized authority in pentecostalism". Does "no" also negate "**as** there is in Roman Catholicism"?

Comment: No, it does not. But the _as_ related to "centralized authoriry", not to "no centralized authority". There are cases of this sort that are genuinely ambiguous; but this is not one, in my view.

Comment: Colin: I think it's only unambiguous (as regards whether the negation is "carried through" by ***as** in/with RC*) because everybody knows the Pope runs the show with RC. The construction itself is inherently ambiguous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think so, because of the words "as **there is**" (emphasis added). If it said "as in Roman Catholicism" it would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace 'as' with 'like' in this context.

The thing is there isn't a centralized authority in Pentecostalism, whereas there is such an authority in Roman Catholicism.